# DB Context - Query to select post from a category

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using DB context approach in my asp.net mvc 4 test project.

Here are my domain classes

Category.cs

```
public class Categroy
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string CategoryName{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Post{ get; set; }
}
```

Post.cs

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

IPostsDateSource.cs

```
public interface IPostsDataSource
{
    IQueryable<Category> Categories{ get; }
    IQueryable<Post> Posts { get; }

    void Save();
}
```

PostsDB.cs

```
public class PostsDB:DbContext,IPostsDataSource
{
    public PostsDB():base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts{ get; set; }

    void IPostsDataSource.Save()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }

    IQueryable<Category> IPostsDataSource.Categories
    {
        get { return Categories; }
    }

    IQueryable<Post> IPostsDataSource.Posts
    {
        get { return Posts; }
    }
}
```

I am using StructureMap for mapping
IoC.cs

```
...
x.For<IPostsDataSource>().HttpContextScoped().Use<PostsDB>();
...
```

In my HomeController I am

```
private IPostDataSource _db;

public HomeController(IAdsDataSource db)
{
    _db = db;
}
```

I can retrieve all the posts by `_db.Posts`

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Posts= _db.Posts;
        ViewBag.Posts = Posts;
        return View();
    }
```

The problem is what query should I write in order to retrieve all posts from a specific categrory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a category has a collection of Posts, then Post entity should have a CategoryID property. You can query base on that CategoryID.

Otherwise you can query the category and retrieve the corresponding list of Posts:

```
var cat = _db.Categories.Where(a => a.Id == catId).FirstOrDefault();
if(cat != null)
    ViewBag.Posts = cat.Posts;
return View();
```

Comment: you can also do _db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == catId).Posts, or _db.Categories.Find(catId).Posts;